# Using different text values with vuetify component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

[image]

I'm interested in using a vuetify expansion panel component in a nuxt project. I'm looking at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels#examples . The exampleas all show the same text and header for each subpanel based on code that looks like:

```
<v-app id="inspire">
<div>
  <div class="text-xs-center mb-3">{{ panel }}</div>
  <v-expansion-panel
    v-model="panel"
    expand
  >
    <v-expansion-panel-content
      v-for="(item, i) in 5"
      :key="i"
    >
      <div slot="header">Item</div>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text class="grey lighten-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-expansion-panel>
      <v-expansion-panel-content v-for="(item,i) in 5" :key="i">
        <div slot="header">Item</div>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

How do I get each subpanel to have a different header and text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an array called `items` or whatever you want to your data object, and each item inside that array is an object which has two properties `header` and `text`, and loop through that array in your template as follows :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      panel: 'Sample panel',
      items: [{
          header: 'item 1',
          text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur'
        },
        {
          header: 'item 2',
          text: 'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et'
        },
        {
          header: 'item 3',
          text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,  dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,  commodo consequat.'
        },
        {
          header: 'item 4',
          text: 'quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea'
        },

      ]
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.4.0/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-expansion-panel>
      <v-expansion-panel-content v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i">
        <div slot="header">{{item.header}}</div>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-text>{{item.text}}</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-app>
</div>
```