# Cannot convert object to primitive value with imported json

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

[image]

I'm trying to dynamically build a vuetify component in a nuxt project ([Using different text values with vuetify component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241588/using-different-text-values-with-vuetify-component)) by importing and iterating through json in a module (https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79).

My json in /static/info.json is:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Johnson, Smith, and Jones Co.",
  "amount": 345.33,
  "Remark": "Pays on time"
}
```

In my vue component I have:

```
  import * as data from '../static/info.json';

  const word = data.name;

  console.log(word); // output 'testing'
  console.log(data); // output 'testing'
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
  // console.log(jsonData); // output 'testing'
```

The line:

```
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
```

causes:

```
 Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

How can I iterate through the imported json?

Comment: Are you exporting something from json file ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would guess data is already an object and doesn't need to be parsed again. The import has turned it into an object. You've already used it with data.name